# Change in $f(x,z)$ with change in $x$ and $z$ =$\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}+\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}+\bigg(\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}*\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}\bigg)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have some function $f(x,z)$ and there is some change in variable $x$ and $z$ at the same time. Is it correct to say that the change is given by

$$\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}+\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}+\bigg(\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}*\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}\bigg)$$

My intuition for this is given by the following example: Suppose $f(x,z)=x*z$. If $x$ changes by $x'$ and $z$ changes by $z'$ then we have

$$f'(x,z)=(x+x')*(z+z')   $$

$$=xz+x'z+z'x+x'z'$$

subtracting the initial $f(x,z)=x*z$ gives the change

$$x'z+z'x+x'z'$$ 
this seems to be similar to

$$\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}+\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}+\bigg(\frac{df(x,z)}{dx}*\frac{df(x,z)}{dz}\bigg)$$

Is this true in general, if not, is it true in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular differential handles perturbations in the domain i.e for a small neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,z_0):=p$ we have,

$$ \Delta f (p) \approx df(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) \ dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(p) \ dz$$

Hence for all $(x,z) \in U$ we have $f(x,z) \approx f(p) + df(p)$. Where is this coming from? Taylor's approximation for $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

$\textbf{Example}$: If you would like to see this in action take $(0.99)^3(1.01)^2$ then we let $f(x,z) = x^3z^2$ and $p = (1,1)$. Then $df(p) = 3(-.01) + 2(.01) = -0.01$ and $f(p) = 1$. And so  $df(p) + f(p) = .99$. You can check that $(.99)^3(1.01)^2 \approx 0.989802$.

Comment: So my statement is wrong in general? Is it true in the specific example or not?

Comment: Also isn't $df(p)=3(-.01)^2+2(0.01)$?

Comment: Yes, that is not the general formula. I couldn't tell you when it works. Of course for the hero function. And no, go through it again. There is no square. Follow the formula. Compute partials, evaluate and multiply that by dx, dy respectively.